# How to create Core Data object to loaded Json data?

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, loaddata

I'm trying to figure out how to create a Core Data object from Json data (provided by Financial Modeling Prep).

The application is structured this way:

- An API_SERVICE class with functions like this:

```
func readJsonIncomeStatementFMP(keywords: String) -> AnyPublisher<[IncomeStatementFMP], Error>  {

        let result = parseQuery(text: keywords)
        var symbol = String()
        
        switch result {
        case .success(let query):
            symbol = query
        case .failure(let error):
            return Fail(error: error).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        
        let urlString = "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/income-statement/\(symbol)?apikey=\(API_KEY)"
        
        let urlResult = parseURL(urlString: urlString)
        switch urlResult {
        case .success(let url):
            return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
                .map({$0.data})
                .decode(type: [IncomeStatementFMP].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
                .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        
        case .failure(let error):
            return Fail(error: error).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    }
```

- A SCREENER view in which the API_SERVICE is called:

```
var body: some View {
        @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
            //CoreData
            @FetchRequest(entity: Entreprise.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "companyName", ascending: true)]) var entreprises: FetchedResults<Entreprise>
        @State var subscribers = Set<AnyCancellable>()
            @ObservedObject var apiServiceFMP = APIServiceFMP()
            @State var resultScreener: [ResultScreener]?
        @State var incomeStatementFMP: [IncomeStatementFMP]?
        
        ZStack{
            VStack{
                ScrollView(.horizontal){

                VStack{
                    Button(action: {
                        handleSelectionStockScreenerMultipleProperties(exchange: exchange, country: country, marketCap: marketCap)
                    }){
                        Text("Lancer le screen")
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color(.green))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                }
                if resultScreener != nil{
                    VStack{
                        List(searchResults, id: \.id){ results in
                            HStack{
                                Text(results.symbol)
                                Divider()
                                Text(results.companyName)
                                Divider()
                                Button(action: {
                                    Task{
                                        await handleSelectionIncomeStatementForFMP(for: results.symbol)
                                        await handleSelectionBalanceSheetForFMP(for: results.symbol)
                                        await handleSelectionCashFlowForFMP(for: results.symbol)
                                        await handleSelectionCompanyOutlookForFMP(for: results.symbol)
                                        await handleSelectionHistoricalDailyPriceFMP(for: results.symbol)
                                    }
                                }){
                                    Text("Infos").foregroundColor(.white)
                                }.buttonStyle(.plain)
                                
                                
                                if incomeStatementFMP != nil && balanceSheetFMP != nil && cashFlowFMP != nil && companyOutlookFMP != nil && historicalDailyPriceFMP != nil && incomeStatementFMP!.count > 0 {
                                    if incomeStatementFMP![0].symbol == results.symbol{
                                        Button(action: {
                                            Task{
                                                await handleSelectionIncomeStatementForFMP(for: results.symbol)
                                                await handleSelectionBalanceSheetForFMP(for: results.symbol)
                                                await handleSelectionCashFlowForFMP(for: results.symbol)
                                                await handleSelectionCompanyOutlookForFMP(for: results.symbol)
                                                await handleSelectionHistoricalDailyPriceFMP(for: results.symbol)
                                            }
                                            addEntreprise(incomeStatementFMP: incomeStatementFMP!, balanceSheetFMP: balanceSheetFMP!, cashFlowFMP: cashFlowFMP!, companyOutlookFMP: companyOutlookFMP!, ticker: results.symbol)
                                        }){
                                            Text("Ajout BDD").foregroundColor(.white)
                                        }.buttonStyle(.plain)
                                        .padding()
                                        .background(.blue)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

private func handleSelectionIncomeStatementForFMP(for symbol: String) async{
 
        apiServiceFMP.readJsonIncomeStatementFMP(keywords: symbol).sink { (completionResult) in
            
            switch completionResult {
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            case .finished: break
            }
        } receiveValue: { (incomeStatementResults) in
            self.incomeStatementFMP = incomeStatementResults
        }.store(in: &subscribers)
    }
private func addEntreprise(incomeStatementFMP: [IncomeStatementFMP], balanceSheetFMP: [BalanceSheetFMP], cashFlowFMP: [CashFlowFMP], companyOutlookFMP: [CompanyOutlookFMP], ticker: String){
        if incomeStatementFMP.count > 0 && balanceSheetFMP.count > 0 && cashFlowFMP.count > 0 {
            if companyOutlookFMP[0].profile.symbol == ticker && incomeStatementFMP.count > 0 && incomeStatementFMP[0].symbol == ticker && balanceSheetFMP[0].symbol == ticker && cashFlowFMP[0].symbol == ticker{
                if entreprises.filter({$0.ticker == ticker}).count != 0 {

                    for entreprise in entreprises.filter({$0.ticker == ticker}){
                        if entreprise.incomes!.count == incomeStatementFMP.count {
                            ///Si les données fondamentales n'ont pas changé, on arrête
                            return
                        }
                        else {
                            ///Si les données fondamentales sont plus nombreuses que celles déjà enregistrées
                            ///Il mettre à jour les données de l'objet existant
                            print("Il faut intégrer la méthode pour modifier l'objet sans le recréer")
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    createNewEntreprise(companyOutlookFMP: companyOutlookFMP, incomeStatementFMP: incomeStatementFMP, balanceSheetFMP: balanceSheetFMP, cashFlowFMP: cashFlowFMP, historicalDailyPriceFMP: historicalDailyPriceFMP!, ticker: ticker)
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Il n'y a pas assez de données, pas d'intérêt d'enregistrer l'entreprise")
        }
    }
    
    func createNewEntreprise(companyOutlookFMP: [CompanyOutlookFMP], incomeStatementFMP: [IncomeStatementFMP], balanceSheetFMP: [BalanceSheetFMP], cashFlowFMP: [CashFlowFMP], historicalDailyPriceFMP: [HistoricalDailyPriceFMP], ticker: String){
        if companyOutlookFMP[0].profile.symbol == ticker && incomeStatementFMP[0].symbol == ticker && balanceSheetFMP[0].symbol == ticker && cashFlowFMP[0].symbol == ticker && historicalDailyPriceFMP[0].symbol == ticker{
            let newEntreprise = Entreprise(context: viewContext)
            newEntreprise.ticker = companyOutlookFMP[0].profile.symbol
            newEntreprise.industry = companyOutlookFMP[0].profile.industry
            newEntreprise.sector = companyOutlookFMP[0].profile.sector
            newEntreprise.companyName = companyOutlookFMP[0].profile.companyName
            
            newEntreprise.currency = companyOutlookFMP[0].profile.currency
            newEntreprise.region = companyOutlookFMP[0].profile.country
            newEntreprise.exchange = companyOutlookFMP[0].profile.exchangeShortName
            
            let s = companyOutlookFMP[0].profile.isin
            let any : Any? = s
            if any != nil {
                newEntreprise.isin = companyOutlookFMP[0].profile.isin
            } else {
                newEntreprise.isin = "Pas de ISIN"
            }

            newEntreprise.lastPrice = Array(getLastDailyPrice(historicalDailyPrice: historicalDailyPriceFMP)).sorted(by: >)[0].value
            newEntreprise.dateLastPrice = Array(getLastDailyPrice(historicalDailyPrice: historicalDailyPriceFMP)).sorted(by: >)[0].key
            
            //Ajouter les données fondamentales
            for i in addIncomeToEnterprise(incomeStatementFMP: incomeStatementFMP){
                newEntreprise.addToIncomes(i)
                //On enregistre les Income Statement
                do {
                    try viewContext.save()
                } catch {
                    let nsError = error as NSError
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
                }
            }
            for i in addBalanceToEnterprise(balanceSheetFMP: balanceSheetFMP){
                newEntreprise.addToBalances(i)
                //On enregistre les Balance Sheet
                do {
                    try viewContext.save()
                } catch {
                    let nsError = error as NSError
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
                }
            }
            for i in addCashToEnterprise(cashFlowFMP: cashFlowFMP){
                newEntreprise.addToCashFlows(i)
                //On enregistre les Cash Flow
                do {
                    try viewContext.save()
                } catch {
                    let nsError = error as NSError
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
                }
            }
            //On enregistre l'objet newEntreprise avec toutes les Relationships
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think we should use the notion of Async Await.

I would like to load the data with one click on "Ajout BDD".

This is where it doesn't work perfectly -> I have to click on the **"Info"** button first which calls the API_SERVICE functions before I can press the **"Ajout BDD"** button which is used to create Core objects Data.

Why when I directly press **"Ajout BDD"** nothing happens? If I press twice it adds the object in Core Data.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your code is very, very hard to understand but why do you call the same handleSelection... functions from both buttons and where in your code is the Core Data part that the title implies you are asking about?

Comment: Hi, I updated the code.
The gist of my question is: how to run function save to Core Data (addEnterprise()) only after incomeStatementFMP, balanceSheetFMP etc. have they been loaded?
The button "Info" helps to load the data so that function addEnterprise() does not fail.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that needs to be improved but it works.
Of the four variables I want to monitor, I added a DidSet :

```
@State var incomeStatementFMP: [IncomeStatementFMP]?{
    didSet{
        observeEntreprise()
    }
}
@State var balanceSheetFMP: [BalanceSheetFMP]?{
    didSet{
        observeEntreprise()
    }
}
@State var cashFlowFMP: [CashFlowFMP]?{
    didSet{
        observeEntreprise()
    }
}
@State var companyOutlookFMP: [CompanyOutlookFMP]?{
    didSet{
        observeEntreprise()
    }
}
```

The rest is handled by the function observeEntreprise :

```
func observeEntreprise(){
    if incomeStatementFMP != nil && balanceSheetFMP != nil && cashFlowFMP != nil && companyOutlookFMP != nil && historicalDailyPriceFMP != nil{
        let newEntreprise = Entreprise(context: viewContext)
        ............
}
```